# React. Как дождатся завершения одного таймера перед запуском другого в цикле

Tags: javascript, react-native

Есть произвольное количество пар значений (название и цена продукта)

Получаю их из сервера и вывожу по одной паре в строку

Необходимо раз в `n` милисекунд поочередно мигнуть `m` раз каждой строкой продолжительностью в `k` милисекунд

Объясните как в цикле следующую итерацию совершать после того как объявленный в текущей итерации таймер отработает (включая рекурсивные вызовы)?

Пробую раз в 10 секунд менять состояние каждой строки 6 раз с задержкой в пол секунды

```
componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function run() {
      let tickCounter = 0;
      for (let key in that.state.fuel) {
        setTimeout(function tick(){
          that.state.visible[key] = !that.state.visible[key];          
          that.setState({ visible: that.state.visible });
          if (++tickCounter != 6) {
            setTimeout(tick, 500);
          }
          else
             tickCounter = 0;
        }, 500);
      }
      setTimeout(run, 5000);     
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: 1. не колхозить кучу таймеров а написать алгоритм с использованием одного; 2. в цикле, в случае рекурсивного вызова `setTimeout`, необходимость отпадает

```
componentDidMount() {
  var roundTime = 5000; // длительность раунда
  var tickTime  = 500; // продолжительность мигания

  var tickCount = 3; // количество миганий
  var tickCurrent = 0; // счетчик миганий

  var stuffCount = 6; // колличество продуктов
  var stuffCurrent = 0; // текущий продукт

  var that = this;

  setTimeout(function run() {
    that.state.visible[stuffCurrent] = !that.state.visible[stuffCurrent];          
    that.setState({ visible: that.state.visible });
    if(stuffCurrent < stuffCount && ++tickCurrent < tickCount * 2) {
      setTimeout(run,tickTime)
    } else if(stuffCurrent < stuffCount && tickCurrent === tickCount * 2) {
      tickCurrent = 0;
      stuffCurrent++;
      setTimeout(run,tickTime);
    } else {
      tickCurrent = 0;
      stuffCurrent = 0;
      setTimeout(run,roundTime);
    }
  }, roundTime);
}
```